# How to check the Vendor ID for your company?

Tags: usb, usb-device

Someone filled out this form a while ago:
http://www.usb.org/developers/vendor/VID_Only_Form_withCCAuth_010113.pdf

I'm looking for a way to lookup vendor ID from company name

```
f(key=company_name) => VID
```

My situation is the final paragraph of the copy on this page (only VID, no membership or logo rights):
http://www.usb.org/developers/vendor/

Comment: A Quick web search came up with [link]{https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/). This doesn't look official and has an invalid https certificate but seems to have the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a list of vendor ID at the usb.org website itself, it is under the tools section: http://www.usb.org/developers/tools/comp_dump this list has the companies and VID in Decimal numbers so you might need to convert it to a Hex number to get the correct one.

Direct link from above is dead. New file has a date attached to filename, so no direct linking is possible. In the URL https://www.usb.org/developers look for "Valid USB Vendor IDs".

Comment: Just open the USB.if file with notepad

Comment: Hmmm ... the list is incomplete. I wonder if it only includes VIDs for companies with a current (un-expired) USB logo license?

Comment: Which VID are you missing ? It could be that the list is incomplete ....

Comment: My company's for one ... 5808 (0x16b0), but assuming sequential assignment, there are many VIDs missing.

Comment: Yea I also have a PDF with all VIDs but I can't directly find it on USB.org, so I don't know if I can disclose this here

Comment: The full list is only available to member companies, so the above list is the bet official you can find

Comment: For posterity, to get the hex conversion easily for the numbers in this file, I used the following awk one-liner: `awk -F'|' '{printf("%04x\t%s\n",$1,$0)}' usb.if`. You can grep the output easily enough.

Comment: Link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 7):

The link http://www.usb.org/developers/tools/comp_dump died during September 2018.

The official and new file can be found here (this took a while to find):
https://cms.usb.org/usb/api/usbif.json

Note that the format is now JSON and all obsolete vendors are also included.

Answer (score 3):

See: http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids for a more complete list of vendor ID's and device ID's.

Comment: I am really hoping someone could explain the 0x4 "Nebraska Furniture Mart". I can see so little discussion about it on the Googlewebs, yet I can't understand what purpose it would serve other than a very particular niche advertising plug

Answer (score 1):

I have found this list included with my Teledyne Lecroy analyser.  I hope it is public information so I am just sharing it for now.  The VIDs are in decimal form. It was called "Companies.inc" originally. 
[list of USB VIDs](http://leobodnar.com/balloons/files/USB-VIDs.txt)